# Infinite while nested in a for loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, while-loop, infinite-loop

I want to make a `while` loop, nested in a `for` loop in Matlab in order to find the distance between different pairs in the data. My data have the following form

```
    ID  lon     lat     time
    1   33.56   40.89   803
    2   32.45   41.03   803
    3   35.78   39.85   803
    2   33.04   40.21   804
    3   36.89   40.23   804
    2   33.98   39.33   806
    2   33.67   39.73   809
    3   37.02   40.77   809
```

`lon` and `lat` are geographical coordinates. In the `for` loop, I want to take the first row from the matrix and then in the `while` loop check all other rows and compute the distance between the pairs as long as the condition in the `while` is `true`. What I mean is that for the first row I want the program to compute the distance between the pairs 1-2, 1-3 at time 803, then the distance 1-2, 1-3 at time 803 again. When I increment the step in the `for` loop by 1, again, the program should compute the distance between the pairs 2-3 at 803, then 2-3 at 804 and so on, so forth. To do that, I've written the `for` loop as below:

```
for ii = 1:length(MM(:,4))
    t = MM(ii,4);
    ind1 = ii;
    length(ind1);
    lat1 = lat(ind1);
    lon1 = lon(ind1);
    jj = ii +1;

    while (t <= (MM(ii,4)+5))
        for jj = 2:length(MM(:,4))
            ind2 = jj;
            length(ind2);
            lat2 = lat(ind2);
            lon2 = lon(ind2);
            w = MM(jj,4);
        end

        dis = distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
        t = t + 1;
    end


    if dis <= 1

        [contact] = [ind1, ind2, t, w];
    end

end
```

With this `for` loop I get an infinite `while` loop. My question is why do I get this infinite `while` loop and how am I supposed to make it work as I described?

Comment: [Use the debugger](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to walk through the code and see what is happening in your loop.

Comment: I used the debugger and I see that the program works only for the first value in the `while` loop. After that it goes in an infinite loop and it does not change any values in the `while`

Comment: So then you need to determine why the values are not changed. Maybe you can print some key values, either in terminal or to file. For example, you may want to print every hundreth or tousand `t`? It is hard for us to say since we do not now the expected range. I do not really think it is a question for SO though. It is rather a private thing between you and the debugger ;).

Comment: However, I notice that the inner for loop is kind of a waste when you only pick the last value. Further `jj` is ferfectly fine to use as index as well and should not be used as a loop variable in case you use it outside the loop, in another loop. [This document](https://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/getstart.pdf) describes the basics of Matlab. I would also guess scope rules is covered, which is not exactly the same as in, for example, java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer. I post it here for future use.

```
for ii = 1:length(MM(:,4))
    t = MM(ii,4);
    ind1 = ii;
    length(ind1);
    lat1 = lat(ind1);
    lon1 = lon(ind1);
    jj = ii + 1;

    while (MM(jj,4) - t <= 5)

            ind2 = jj;
            length(ind2);
            lat2 = lat(ind2);
            lon2 = lon(ind2);
            dis = distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);

            if dis <= 1
                contact = [MM(ind1,1), MM(ind2,1), t, MM(jj,4)]   

            else
                fprintf('There is no distance smaller than 1km\n')
            end

            jj = jj + 1;
    end

end
```

As it seems the nested `for` loop in the `while` was wrong and without any use at all. The second problem was the condition in the `while`. The comparison, I previously made in the `while` condition was written backwards and had no meaning. And the third problem was the `if` statement. By putting the `if` statement in the `while` loop, I had the result in the contact.